# Evento para quando o usuario for sair da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de fazer um modelo igual ao do site catraca livre. Como poderia fazer isto? Se consiste em quando o mouse sair da pagina aparecer um `alert` questionando se o usuário realmente deseja deixar a página. Qual o evento javascript que faz isso alguém sabe ?

Comment: tem como enviar a URL para demonstrar o comportamento desejado?

Comment: https://catracalivre.com.br/curitiba/agenda/barato/fernando-meirelles-debate-os-novos-rumos-do-cinema-no-teatro-bom-jesus/

Comment: **Não existe tal evento**. O algoritmo utilizado nesse site é muito bem trabalhado, pelo que pude perceber ele considera *scroll* da página, tempo de permanência e rastreamento do mouse, a solução é fazer engenharia reversa. Nota: não se trata de um `alert()`, mas sim um *modal* ([exemplo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo))

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você esteja procurando por este evento:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){return "Deseja mesmo sair do site?"};
```

Isto irá exibir uma janela de confirmação quando o usuário clicar para fechar a guia.

Comment: tem como colocar alert e nao ser uma janela de confirmacao por exemplo so coloca um alert pra avisa ele? se tiver como creio eu que sim seria este evento mesmo que quando passar o mouse nas guia ele dar essa informacao

Comment: nao e desse modo que eu quero eu so quero um alert quando ele passa o mouse na guia so quero q apareca isso um alert quando ele passa o mouse na guia

Answer (score 1):

Apesar da pergunta ser de algum tempo atrás, percebi não ter nenhuma resposta que realmente responda a pergunta, então para quem tiver a mesma duvida e acabar caindo nesse post.

Basta usar o evento `mouseleave` do *JQuery* no `body`.

```
$('body').mouseleave(function(){
    alert('O Usuário tirou o mouse da página');
})
```

No lugar do alert você faz o que for necessário, como colocar um pop up para "segurar" o usuário na página.