# Capturar ação de Recarregamento de Pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como pegar a ação do usuário quando ele clica sobre a seta de recarregar a pagina ou quando ele da enter na URL, no google chrome. Usando javaScript.

Comment: o evento *hashchange* atende? `$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
     //codigo aqui
});`

Comment: Relacionadas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96283/evento-para-quando-o-usuario-for-sair-da-pagina e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307483/É-possível-adicionar-um-ouvinte-de-evento-na-url

Answer (score -2):

São contextos diferentes.
O Enter do do navegador ocorre dentro da aplicação do navegador e não no ambiente javascript. O navegador por sua vez inicia ou finaliza o processo.

Os principais eventos iniciais e finais a partir do javascript é:

Ao concluir carregamento do conteudo:
"onload":

Ao sair:
"onbeforeunload":

Alguns navegadores bloqueiam essas funções para o usuário não ficar preso a página por um script.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).